# Informative versus Question / Answer Format

Tags: feature-request, self-answer

Most of the time when I ask a question on Stack Overflow, I find myself in such a conundrum that I fully expect another user will arrive at a solution before I do, but that is not always the case. As such, I post my own answer to it and later accept it if there are no better solutions offered. Not that it happens often, but occasionally I have seen other users (perhaps those who had been working on a solution) retaliate in various ways- most recently by flagging a perfectly well-formed question as overly-broad, and more often with revengeful down-votes.

That said, I think it would be a nice feature to offer converting the answer / question format in these cases into one that is informative. If put into a review queue thereafter, it could offer users the ability to vote to accept or reject, and so keeps in line with the spirit of the site.

Has this idea been proposed and given serious consideration before?

Beyond improving the social dynamic, I believe it would also improve the content. Undoubtably, there are many questions that go unanswered because the author neglected to post a perfectly valid answer to his or her own question for any reason, but I do suspect peer pressure could be a factor.

Comment: I would love to see your mind reading device.

Comment: Which mind reading device?

Comment: The one that gives you the ability to gain absolute insight into the motivation behind users actions.

Comment: "*I have seen other users ... retaliate ... by flagging a perfectly well-formed question as overly-broad, and ... revengeful down-votes.*" Sure seems like you have a mind reading device.

Comment: It is not difficult to infer with near real-time updates and less than 11 views on a question. Plus, there is the timing of when people make comments.

Comment: There are also millions of users on Stack Overflow constantly voting, and a huge difference between fact and inference.

Comment: Of course, but there are not millions of users viewing and voting on my questions so it does make it easier to make an inference. If I had access to the data I would need to confirm or refute the assumption, then I would take it to task and give an honest interpretation, but in this case, I only have my eyes. Regardless, I think what I recommended is a good suggestion.

Comment: All of the [se] sites are designed to be **question and answer** sites, which means there first needs to be a question asked and then an answer can be posted. (This is covered in the [help] for all of the sites, in the section titled *Our Model* and in the [tour].) If you want to write an *informative post* that does not fit the Q&A format, post it to your blog.

Comment: "mind reading device" You guys are so easily tickled these days, it hurts.

Comment: Yes, there is the remote possibility that someone downvoted a self-answered question for entirely innocuous reasons. A minority of self-answered questions are pretty bad. But every time someone pulls the "mind reading" card, I think of all the custom flags we've received alleging really great self-answered questions to be breaking some imaginary rule, and I wonder just how likely it is that someone would vote fairly on a self-answered question.

Comment: @BoltClock I find the vast majority of self answered questions are just bad posts.  It's really hard to write a good self answered question.  Much harder than asking a question you don't know the answer to or answering someone else's question. I'd expect that if you just anonymized the user cards for self-answered questions you'd find that their average scores were notably lower than the overall average scores of posts. To assume that most downvotes on self answered posts aren't evaluating the quality of the post is just absurd.  Those people casting those flags are not the majority of voters.

Comment: While there are no down votes on this one self-answered post, the complaint from several was that the question was overly-broad. Immediately after accepting my own answer, the question was put on hold by votes from other users even though at least one person took and interest in it prior, and I even got a compliment on the provided answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056658/how-to-calculate-balanced-tiers-on-ranked-values

Comment: [Avg self-answer score is positive](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/356452), @Servy. Lower than the average answer score, but... Still positive. Median is 0, median for answers in general is 1. Self-answering is hard, but then again so is answering: in both cases, the common result is neither very good nor very bad; it doesn't take *many* votes to skew the final scores.

Comment: @Shog9 So that's entirely in line with my prediction.  Too few people actually downvote low quality content, so I'm not surprised that the average score is positive, but it is lower than non-self answered posts.  I'd also expect the question half of self answered posts to be further from the non-self answered posts than the answer portion.  Too many people just write a blog, post it as an answer, and stick a garbage question above it just so it lets them post the answer.

Comment: Easy enough to run those numbers yourself, @Servy. My point was simply that it doesn't take an overwhelming number of biased readers to cause a significant skew.

Comment: Setting aside all the talk about supposed revenge voting, I still do believe the feature I suggested would be a good one, and it seems it could be supportable on the basis of what others have said about self-answered questions usually being lower quality. However, I want to be clear- I am not suggesting  a "blog" feature. A person would still have to ask a question, wait for answers, and accept their own answer after a required waiting period. After, there could be an option to convert the format.

Comment: Interesting tool. I did not know that was offered.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're suggesting here. If you're suggesting that self answered posts should read more like blog posts, I don't think that will gain any traction. Stack Overflow prides itself on its clear cut Q&A format.

[Self answered questions are encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking?lq=1) so, I doubt that there is any connection between the relatively few downvotes/close-votes you've received and your self answered question.

**Correlation != causation.**

Revenge voting is usually a lot more vindictive. It looks like you've only received a handful of downvotes since you joined the network. If I'm not mistaken only 6 in 8 months, not great, but certainly nothing to get too concerned about.

Take each vote as a learning experience, if you're getting downvoted ask yourself what you can do to improve the post rather than trying to assign motives.

Comment: Thanks! I have been on the site much longer than my profile leads on though (since about 2009). I decided not long ago to start posting under my given name. I understand the pride behind the Q & A format, but I still do believe it would be a good idea to allow users to convert certain questions to an informational format, even if that content is promoted less.

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann What do you mean by "an informational format"?

Comment: Really what I mean is something along the lines of- this is the challenge I faced, the initial question I asked, and how I resolved it. Hope it helps somebody else facing the same.

Comment: "Self answered questions are encouraged" -- officially, yes; in practice, it seems as though they're almost always gone over with a more critical eye and less forgiving voting patterns. (Which is saying something, on SO.)